Why I can't start Django web site with docker?
I have a Django web app and I need to launch it with docker. I created two images: one for Django and another for postgresql. It successfully builds but during the composing up shows the problem that django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 or psycopg module. Seems like docker didn't install psycopg2 from requirements.txt.
Dockerfile:
# Here I'm creating an image for Django.
FROM python:3.10.0-alpine

COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt 
COPY movies_admin /movies_admin
WORKDIR /movies_admin

EXPOSE 8000

RUN apk add postgresql-client build-base postgresql-dev

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt 

docker-compose.yml
services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

    volumes:
      - "./movies_admin:/movies_admin"

    environment:
      - DB_HOST=database
      - POSTGRES_DB=movies_database
      - POSTGRES_USER=app
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123qwe

    command:
      sh -c "python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"

    depends_on:
      - database

  database:

    image: postgres:16

    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=movies_database
      - POSTGRES_USER=app
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123qwe

requirements.txt
asgiref==3.8.1
autopep8==2.1.0
black==24.3.0
click==8.1.7
Django==5.0.4
django-split-settings==1.3.1
flake8==7.0.0
mccabe==0.7.0
mypy-extensions==1.0.0
packaging==24.0
pathspec==0.12.1
platformdirs==4.2.0
psycopg2==2.9.9
psycopg2-binary==2.9.9
pycodestyle==2.11.1
pyflakes==3.2.0
python-dotenv==1.0.1
sqlparse==0.4.4
tomli==2.0.1
typing_extensions==4.11.0


I suggest restructuring your Dockerfile like this:
FROM python:3.10.0-alpine

RUN apk add postgresql-client build-base postgresql-dev

WORKDIR /movies_admin

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

COPY movies_admin .

Why does this work? The requirements.txt file is copied across into the working directory and then the packages are immediately installed. This ensures that you get the correct packages! In the Dockerfile from the question the requirements.txt file is copied across into the root directory /requirements.txt. But then you change working directory to /movies_admin, so that when you run pip install -r requirements.txt it's trying to use the file in /movies_admin rather than the one you copied across to /requirements.txt.
That assumes that your project layout looks something like this:
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── movies_admin
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── manage.py
│   └── movies_admin
│       ├── asgi.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── settings.py
│       ├── urls.py
│       └── wsgi.py
└── requirements.txt

 The requirements.txt file is in the same directory as docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile.
To complete this setup you'd just need to ensure that your database is correctly configured in your Django settings.py:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'movies_database',
        'USER': 'app',
        'PASSWORD': '123qwe',
        'HOST': 'database',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


Thanks for detailed answer. I successfully solve this problem :) but why when I starts my app in docker it shows an empty database if it’s already full outside docker? Why do i need to migrate inside docker if i did it beforehand?

I'm not sure that I understand. What do you mean by the database being "full" outside of Docker? You are running a database container inside your Docker Compose stack. Do you mean that you have a database running on the host as well?

I created and populated a postgresql database before I started containerizing the website. Then, I wrote a dockerfile for django and took the prebuilt postgres image, ran docker compose up and now my web site runs through docker. However, I noticed that the database is empty, as if it has not been moved to docker (inside docker my postresql empty). Sounds like your Docker setup isn't properly linking to your existing PostgreSQL database.

With the docker-compose.yml stack you provide you are creating a second service, database, using the postgres:16 image. This database will be empty until you have populated it. The database that you created "before I started containerizing the website" lives outside of the Docker Compose stack and is completely separate. If you want to use your existing database with this stack then you'll need to share those data with the database service perhaps by using a volume mount.

Thank you, @datawookie! I've successfully solved this problem simply by adding volumes: - $HOME/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data. I found the path of my existing db in another container.
